# Unable to load "sfFacebookConnectHelper.php" helper

Tags: plugins, symfony1, symfony-1.4, helper

im trying to build FB application demo with [sfFacebookConnectPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFacebookConnectPlugin) by [this tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/12-Developing-for-Facebook#chapter_12_sub_connecting_sfguard_with_facebook) and i have trivial problem, but still cannot fix it (iam symfony novice using 1.4).
I have installed this plugins by terminal commands:

- sfDoctrineGuardPlugin
- sfFacebookConnectPlugin

I have them activated in:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
      if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
        date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());
      }
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfBehatPlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrineGuardPlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfFacebookConnectPlugin');
  }
}
```

But When iam using in my layout:

```
<?php use_helper('sfFacebookConnect')?>
```

Im getting this error:

```
Unable to load "sfFacebookConnectHelper.php" helper
in: SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/frontend/modules/main/lib/helper,
SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/frontend/lib/helper,
SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/helper,
SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/helper.
```

While The helper is present in **/home/palmic/www/behattest/plugins/lib/helper/sfFacebookConnectHelper.php**

How to tell symfony to load it from there?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary fix (until the developers who wrote the plugin move their helper), you can create your own sfFacebookConnectHelper file in `SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/helper` that contains the following code:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../plugins/sfFacebookConnectPlugin/lib/sfFacebookConnectHelper.php';
```

That path might be wrong, so just point it to wherever their helper is.

Then you can still use `<?php use_helper('sfFacebookConnect')?>` in your code, and when the real helper gets moved to the correct folder, just delete this file.

Also, a small tip. Instead of calling `$this->enablePlugins()` repeatedly in your ProjectConfiguration file, you can do this:

```
$this->enablePlugins(array(
  'sfDoctrinePlugin',
  'sfBehatPlugin',
  'sfDoctrineGuardPlugin',
  'sfFacebookConnectPlugin'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in plugin itself, helpers and other lib classes has to be in plugins/<plugin-name>/lib directory so that plugin helpers has to be in:

```
plugins/<plugin-name>/lib/helper
```

not in plugins/lib.